# Error loading project in VS 2022 and 2019 Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This happens when I load a web project. Anyone run into this before ? One day it was working and now its not no updates or anything

> SDK Resolver Failure: "The SDK resolver
> "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver" failed while attempting to
> resolve the SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web". Exception:
> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External
> component has thrown an exception.    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.NativeWrapper.Interop.Windows.hostfxr_resolve_sdk2(String
> exe_dir, String working_dir, hostfxr_resolve_sdk2_flags_t flags,
> hostfxr_resolve_sdk2_result_fn result)    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.NativeWrapper.NETCoreSdkResolverNativeWrapper.ResolveSdk(String
> dotnetExeDirectory, String globalJsonStartDirectory, Boolean
> disallowPrerelease)    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.DotNetSdkResolver.NETCoreSdkResolver.ResolveNETCoreSdkDirectory(String
> globalJsonStartDir, Version msbuildVersion, Boolean
> isRunningInVisualStudio, String dotnetExeDir)    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver.DotNetMSBuildSdkResolver.Resolve(SdkReference
> sdkReference, SdkResolverContext context, SdkResultFactory factory)
> at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResolverService.ResolveSdk(Int32
> submissionId, SdkReference sdk, LoggingContext loggingContext,
> ElementLocation sdkReferenceLocation, String solutionPath, String
> projectPath, Boolean interactive, Boolean isRunningInVisualStudio)""
> C:\dev\S3.Core\S3.Core\S3.Core.Web.ControlCenter\S3.Core.Web.ControlCenter.csproj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done something to screw up my launchsettings.json. I reverted it and it fixed everything